# ReactJS: button onclick doesn't do anythning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting quite confused with this one. When i'm trying to make a button which does something, and use it via innerhtml (I know it is dangerous to use for XSS reasons). However, once i click this button, it simply doesn't do anything.

This is my file

```
    import React from "react";

    class ListOfPoints extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
          punten: props.punten,
          puntenlengte : props.puntenlengte,
          gebiedsGrootte : props.GebiedsGrootte



        };
      }
    consoleLogIets(){
        console.log("punten")
    }

    render(){
        const {id, punten, puntenlengte, GebiedsGrootte} = this.state;
    return (
        <>
        <div className="row m-3 p-4 block rounded">
            <div className="col m-3 p-4">
                <h1>{id}</h1>
                <h3>Gebiedsgrootte: {GebiedsGrootte}</h3>
                <h3>Geselecteerde locaties: {puntenlengte}</h3>
                {punten.forEach(element => {
                    <>{element}</>
                })}
                </div>

            <div className="col m-3 p-4">
            <input placeholder="Naam"></input>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.consoleLogIets}>Klik hier om op te slaan</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </>
)}
}
export default ListOfPoints;
```

Is there someone who can explain why this doesn't work? Is it because of InnerHTML Simply not being able use a onClick function? or a totally different problem which im currently not seeing?

I've tried some things, but none of them work whatsovever.

Comment: You need to call the function using () and bind the current instance (this) in class components

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

class ListOfPoints extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: props.id,
      punten: props.punten,
      puntenlengte : props.puntenlengte,
      gebiedsGrootte : props.GebiedsGrootte



    };
  }
consoleLogIets(){
    console.log("punten")
}

render(){
    const {id, punten, puntenlengte, GebiedsGrootte} = this.state;
return (
    <>
    <div className="row m-3 p-4 block rounded">
        <div className="col m-3 p-4">
            <h1>{id}</h1>
            <h3>Gebiedsgrootte: {GebiedsGrootte}</h3>
            <h3>Geselecteerde locaties: {puntenlengte}</h3>
            {punten.forEach(element => {
                <>{element}</>
            })}
            </div>

        <div className="col m-3 p-4">
        <input placeholder="Naam"></input>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.consoleLogIets.bind(this)}>Klik hier om op te slaan</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </>
)} } 

export default ListOfPoints;`
```

You havent called the function while click

Best method define the function with state in constructor and call the function on click

Comment: This, sadly, doen't fix my problem. Once i press the button, it should just simply do a console log. When i use this code only, instead of a innerhtml, it does work. Is this a problem within innerhtml?

Comment: create a sandbox example with your code, and share the link
Will correct with exact code

Comment: The problem is, is my website runs via an API which runs on localhost. I, sadly, dont have a clue how to include this API in the sandbox...